# Lock a boolean method (How to return nothing from a boolean method or discard)

Tags: java

I have a `private boolean status;` field.

I'm trying to lock a class methods in this way:

`status == true` means class is locked and `status == false` means class is unlock

if the class has been locked so methods cant invoke like:

```
  protected void flip ()
    {
        if (locked()) return;
        face = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    }
```

To understand the problem, consider this:

```
   protected boolean isHeads ()
    {
    //if(!locked()) return false or true;
    //if I write upper command then its true or false like the bottom command and its unclear that this false or true is for which of them
    //if(!locked())
    //if i write this command then i have to write another return and its the same problem too;
        return (face == HEADS);
        
    }
```

P.S: I have an interface so I can't change the method about `locked()` and lock and etc;

Comment: Do you really need to block methods that don't change the state of your object? If so, `throw new RuntimeException();`. This will totally break all calling code, but doing what you're asking will do so anyway.

Comment: yes i need this,could you give me example code plz  @Siguza

Comment: You can change your method to return a Boolean object, then you can return null if you do not want to return true or false. 
Alternatively if you are on Java8, you can return an Optional<Boolean>.

Comment: it seems good but im new in java a new bool obj :O could u please write an example code @mdewit

Comment: I actually prefer the CarloCe's answer to throw an exception when the class is locked. However just change your function from "protected boolean isHeads()" to "protected Boolean isHeads()". Now you are allowed to return null in addition to true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct design for such kind of programming is to throw an exception, so the code should be something like this:

```
protected boolean isHeads () throws ObjectIsLockedException
{
    if(locked()) throw new ObjectIsLockedException();
    return (face == HEADS);
}
```

Note that `ObjectIsLockedExpception` is not a Java exception: you have to declare it as a class in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return nothing from a boolean method. It has to be true or false. Return an int or enum or make the function wait.